# TextureView: Perform TextureView.getBitmap() in Background

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, textureview

I am displaying `CameraView` in `TextureView` and am using `TextureView.getBitmap()` to get bitmaps from the `TextureView`.

Each time i call `TextureView.getBitmap()` it causes the Camera preview to freeze for a nano second. I would like to run this task in the background.

Thanks

here is the code i've tried:

```
     findViewById(R.id.capture).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             Bitmap bmp =  mTextureView.getBitmap();  
             rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
             rev.add(bmp);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ rev.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        });
```

Here is my Logcat

```
       08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859): java.lang.NullPointerException
        08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at                              com.example.hangout_gif_camera.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
      08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):   at            android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
     08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):    at       android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
     08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):    at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at         android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
     08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
   08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
      08-22 03:59:57.867: E/AndroidRuntime(4859):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 freeze for a nano second
```

You wont even gonna realize that it freezes our eyes cant react that fast (except if you are superman).

But if you really want it to run in a separate Thread you can try this:

**EDIT:**

```
findViewById(R.id.capture).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                 Thread td = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run()
                   {
                         Bitmap bmp =  mTextureView.getBitmap();  
                         rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                         rev.add(bmp);
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ rev.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                   }
                 });
                 td.start(); //start the thread

               }
            });
```

Comment: it causes my app to crash

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi can you post the logcat

Comment: Rod_Algonquin i just posted it

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi what is line 41?

Comment: Rod_Algonquin the Toast message

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi ahhh, I know now, it should be inside the thread. and make sure you run it inside main thread by calling runOnUiThread

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi see EDIT above.

Comment: it still show error.Not your fault though. its because textureview requires hardware acceleration to run and hardware acceleration can only be used on one thread. can you kindly make an async task for this?

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi then if that is the problem running it in asynchronous wont help, I recommend dont run it on a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fire `TextureView.getBitmap()` on the on the main UI thread.  Then pass that `Bitmap` off to an `AsyncTask` and do the rest there.  That's how I'm doing it and it works fine.

Beware of memory issues if you are capturing every frame of the `TextureView`, for example from `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: I've found that getting a 1920x1080 bitmap on a Galaxy S5 takes about 50ms, which is pretty substantial for the UI thread. At half-size, it takes about 15ms, and quarter-size is about 5ms. So, this solution works (and is probably the only option), but I still don't think its performance is great. :/